# No longer able to re-order custom groups in Microsoft Access navigation pane

Tags: ms-access

After not using Microsoft Access much for about 3 years, I discover I'm not able to drag & drop to re-order groups in the Navigation Pane while in 'Custom' view.

What am I missing? Did they remove it? Break it? Bad update? A setting I've overlooked?

This is for Access 365 installed locally on my C: drive.

The last version of Access I used was 2007. I used it extensively until 2020, and I lived it & breathed it every day. In my main "Workbench" db, I had 2,000+ objects, and 100+ groups to keep them organized. If MS removed the reordering feature, I think my head may explode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same thing happened to me. I discovered they moved it to the File menu and database options screen.

Navigate to `File > Options > Current Database`. Scroll down to the Navigation section, and you will see a `Navigation Options...` button. It is all there.

Also, at the top of the Navigation Pane, right click the banner text which says "Custom", and choose `Navigation Options...`.

Here is a screenshot (added by the OP)...

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thanks. That's super-sneaky. They moved that ability into the options, yet one can still pick up the group names and drag them around the screen, but when dropped they snap back to their original position in the list. Crazy. - I will add a screenshot for this to your post. Thanks again.